# jQuery - Change 1-24 hour to 1-12 hour using .getHours() method?

Tags: jquery, time, hour

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bnsex/1/

I want to use 12 hour clock for this code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

setInterval( function() {
var hours = new Date().getHours();
$(".hours, .hour").html(( hours < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + hours);
}, 1000);

}); ​
```

Your help is much appreciated :D

Comment: Everything you need is in your example.

Comment: I would have to use an If statement, right?

Comment: like if (hours > 12) {
        hours -= 12;
    } else if (hours === 0) {
        hours = 12;
    } ... I'm barely learning jquery. I need some help haha

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the modulus `%` operator, which finds the remainder of a division operation.

For example, `11 % 12` and `23 % 12` both equal 11, like a 12-hour clock would portray.

```
var hours = new Date().getHours() % 12;
if (hours == 0) {
    hours += 12;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ph7Vf/

Comment: Actually, there's a problem... right now its 12:08 pacific time... your code actually displays 00:08 right now. :/

Comment: Good point; I misunderstood how you wanted it to handle that case.  I've edited the answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
hours = (hours < 12 ? hours : hours - 12).toString().replace(/^\d{1}$/, '0$&');
```

**Edit:** It could be shorter, based on Vulcan's answer:

```
hours = (hours % 12).toString().replace(/^\d{1}$/, '0$&');
```

Comment: This is far less efficient than the modulus approach.

Comment: @Vulcan: I just added a revision with your approach. The `replace` is to avoid another condition. @RickyCortes: I would write it like this, but hey feel free to take bits here and pieces there and roll your own solution.